# can I do my PPLA license in spain even if I live in Germany?

Tags: ppl, eu, germany, spain

I live in Germany but I was born in Spain, I wpuld like as a hobby, to get my PPLA license..
but I would like to do that in Spain, if so, can I still flight in germany?

is that possible?

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Yes, an EASA PPL is valid in all EASA member states

Comment: Could you add some sources to back up your answer?